# A function which takes two arguments, an array and an element and it returns the index of the given element

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, arraylist

I have to create a function which takes two arguments, an array and an element and it returns the index of the given element.
I tried this:

```
function findPosition(arr, idx){
    return arr.indexOf(idx);
 }
```

But It's not working as expected.
You know how can I improve it? or make it right.

Comment: Without knowing what's the arguments actually are, it seems it's the correct answer.

Comment: Not enough description here. The array is null, the element is null, the element does not exist in the array. etc. - there are a lot of different errors possible. Please put the exact error from the output, only then someone can help you.

Comment: Like, for example, I've tried with the array [1,2,3,4,5,6], and then element 5 wich should output index 4 and it works, but... , nevermind, it works, I'm wasting posts in here.